# How to route to Navbar inside a navbar

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5if2B.png)I have home component has a nav bar and inside the component div there is an other navbar. I want to open the link in this navbar to opened in the same div that contain that navbar. Couldn't do it. Anyone who can help the code is like that:
the app.compoent is

```
<body class="bg-dark" >
   <div class=" border solid bg-light justify-content-center">
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
 </body>
```

and this the home

```
<div class="bg-secondary"  style="border:1px solid #333">
    <app-sub-nav-menu></app-sub-nav-menu>
  </div>
```

I tried with router with name

```
{ path: 'contacts', component: CarouselComponent, outlet: "outlet1" }
```

and put that in the sub-nav-menu compoent

but it didn't work.
it didn't show anything in the broswer bar  when I click on the link.

Comment: Hi there! It's hard to understand your problem without seeing it. Can you maybe create a working demo (with what you got so far that is) with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or something?

Comment: Thank you. If you look on the image sent with the post might be easier to understand. if not I ll try to make a demo. rgrds

Comment: I made a demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nbce8z?file=src/app/home/home.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the router link active maybe it works for you.
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive